# Display the 0 number on the left-hand side for Oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm doing the Oracle form but all of number in my form are displayed without the 0 if they're smaller than 1,so how to display the decimal number with the 0 number in the left-hand side? I tried to change the Format mask property but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Format Mask property to one that always shows the 0. For example something like this woudl work: `999G999G990D00`. Note the 0 before the `D` (decimal separator).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked